# Gtk3 Invalid cast from 'GtkHeaderBar' to 'GtkMenuShell'

Tags: gtk3

I recently upgraded from debian 11 bullseye to debian 12 bookworm and noticed that

gtk was upgraded from 3.24.24-4 to 3.24.36-4
and
glib was upgraded from 2.66.8-1 to 2.74.5-1.

I have a Gtk3 application which was working fine on debian 11, but now throws several Glib-GObject warnings.

The application uses client side decorations with GtkHeaderBar and a small menu on each window's headerbar.

The warning is:

```
Glib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:15:37.638: invalid cast from 'GtkHeaderBar' to 'GtkMenuShell'
```

Does anyone know if there is an easy solution to this or would it be better to remove client side decorations?

Comment: I'm using GtkBuilder with Glade, so there is no source code to show.